# Broken UTF-8 display in XFCE terminal after upgrade to 4.8

Tags: xfce, utf-8

After a recent archlinux upgrade via `pacman -Suy` I lost UTF-8 display in terminals under xorg. This affects lxterminal, XFCE's terminal, and kde's konsole. I use XFCE 4.6 as window manager.

In my `/etc/rc.conf` I do have the line `LOCALE="en_US.UTF-8"` but non-ascii characters still show in terminal as funny symbols. UTF-8 characters are displayed fine in virutal consoles (accessible via ctr+alt+f1..) and in SSH sessions via putty. Also gnome-terminal displays UTF-8 without problems.

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: What exactly do they look like? If you type `printf '\xe2\x99\xaa\n';` does it output "`♪`" or "`â™Ş`" or "`�`"?

Comment: The second, i.e. "�".

Answer (score 0):

I got my UTF-8 console back after renaming my `~/.config` folder, and also looking through the pacman update logs (`/var/log/pacman.log`) and  merging the `.pacnew` files mentioned in the 'warning' lines.

Comment: but if you rename the .config directory don't you lost all your old configuration?

Comment: 2tokland: yes, you lose some config settings, but since I had not deleted the folder but renamed it, I could copy over the customized files which I needed. Anyway, most config files under ~/.config are generic and seldom contain anything important.